# How route can be drawn in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mkmapview, mapkit

Suppose I have array of points.I want to draw the route of that points in iphone. How it can be done. i dont get the  appropriate answer till now . plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i use Quartz to draw the path between that points.I take two points and draw line between that points and so on till the end of the array and it gives the route between starting point and end point.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D called coords:

```
int size = sizeof(coords[0]) / sizeof(coords);

MKPolyline* line = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:size];

[mapView addOverlay:line];
```